# Not able to align the button and textView in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem in aligning an button and textView. I already have an textView and button in xml and i want another set of those, just below them.
But i am not able to add it. Please have a look at it.

Here is the xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
    <com.aavishkaar.quikies.widget.TypedfacedTextViewxmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.aavishkaar.quickies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Click Here"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        your_namespace:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_light" />

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="ON"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: This is the layout design view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code just change orientation in your first linear layout by default linear layout orientation is horizontal

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">


<com.aavishkaar.quikies.widget.TypedfacedTextView
          xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.aavishkaar.quickies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Click Here"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        your_namespace:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        />

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_light"

        />

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="ON"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
  <com.aavishkaar.quikies.widget.TypedfacedTextView               
   xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.aavishkaar.quickies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Click Here"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        your_namespace:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        />

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_light"

        />

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="ON"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked!:) Do you know how to add a line between them, i.e a divider..

Comment: add a linear layout with orientation horizontal and height 2dp or as you want to give   and background as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
    android:orientation="vertical"  in first Linear Layour.
```

Add

```
    android:orientation="horizontal" in Second Linear Layour.
```

I hope this will work , if not ignore this answer .
I'm Not very Good at this.

Comment: Second Set is Not Visible or Not Alligned?